# Выводятся из базы дубликаты - smarty 2.6.18

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

Здравствуйте.

Использую смарти. Вывожу данные из базы. Делаю так:

```
{foreach from=$row item=data}
    {foreach from=$data item=data}
        <p>{$data}</p>
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

На выходе у меня:

```
16
16
PMUSD
PMUSD
PM
PM
...
```

Почему выводятся дубликаты?

P.S. Смена переменных, не решает проблемы.

Answer (score 1):

Смена переменной должна решить проблему. Попробуйте так:

```
{foreach $row as $data}
    {foreach $data as $item}
        <p>{$item}</p>
    {/foreach}
{/foreach}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но как я писал выше, увы смена переменной не решает проблемы :=(

Comment: А так? Внес изменения. Пришлось лезть в мануалы )

Comment: Этот вариант, я пробовал ранее и щас еще раз перепроверил. Но в этом варианте, увы вообще ничего не выводится

Comment: А что попадает в $row? Потому как называется переменная ряд.

Comment: В переменную `$row` передается значения, полученные из базы данных, которые я получил вот таким вот способом: `$row = $sql->fetchAll()`

Comment: Возможно, вы до этого именно в таком виде их в базу сохранили.